# Convert minutes to full hours without days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

For heavy machinery, one often needs to know the number of hours a machine ran. I have a dataframe with start times and end times. For each time the machine is used, I calculate the minutes the machine was used. This results in a column `df['minutes']`.

How do I convert minutes to hours? For 3,346 minutes, I should get 55 hours and 46 minutes, or `55:46`.

Use this as a working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['minutes'], data =[3346])
```

- If I use this, I get `07:46`:

  ```
    df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['minutes'], unit='m').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
  ```
- If I use this, I get `03 07:46 07:46`:

  ```
    df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['minutes'], unit='m').dt.strftime('%d %H:%M')
  ```

  Why the three (03)?
- I also tried to use apply and gmtime to the column of minutes, which returns `03 07:46`:

  ```
    def dur_time1(x):
        x*=60
        x = time.gmtime(x)
        x = time.strftime("%d %H:%M", x)
        return x

    df['duration'] = df['minutes'].apply(dur_time1)
  ```
- Lastly, I tried to use apply and timedelta to the column of minutes, which returns `2 days 07:46:00`:

  ```
    def dur_time2(x):
        x*=60
        x = timedelta(seconds = x)
        return x

    df['duration'] = df['minutes'].apply(dur_time2)
  ```

  I can live with the 2 days, which I can split off and multiply by 24. But that seems convoluted.

But none of these solutions show 55 hours and 46 minutes.

Comment: It's not your problem, but your functions are not well written. Don't keep overwriting the parameter, give parameters and variables meaningful names. The second one could be `def calculate_duration(minutes): return timedelta(seconds=minutes * 60)`, then it's clear what's happening and why. Calculating total hours from minutes is trivial, though, you don't need to import any modules - it's `minutes // 60` hours and `minutes % 60` minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use this function :

```
def minutes_to_hours(minutes : int):
    time = '{}:{}'.format(minutes//60,minutes%60)
    return time
```

**output :**

```
55:46
```

Comment: f-string seems more appropriate as of 2022: `f'{minutes//60}:{minutes%60}'`

Answer (score 1):

`divmod` is also an option:

```py
def minutes_to_hours(minutes: int):
    return '{}:{}'.format(*divmod(minutes,60))
```

Comment: Should be faster as well (2 calls vs 1)

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no issues with your results. Python did just what you wanted it to do.

Case 1: You asked python to give you the hours and minutes in the time component.

```
df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['minutes'], unit='m').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Case 2: You asked python to give you the days, hours and minutes in the time component.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['minutes'], unit='m').dt.strftime('%d %H:%M')
```

From documentation `%d` does the following;
[image]

python is a C compiler. in C `tm_mday` starts from 1 to find the next/previous days. Simply put;

```
strftime() takes an
       argument of data type time_t, which represents calendar time.
       When interpreted as an absolute time value, it represents the
       number of seconds elapsed since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00
       +0000 (UTC)
```

In your case, because you have `55.766667 hours` in this time component, `strftime('%d %H:%M')` is  interpreting it as `3rd day, 7th Hour 46th Minute since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)`. If you change it to `pd.to_datetime(df['minutes'], unit='m').dt.strftime('%d %I:%M')`, you realise it pads it with a 0.

If you wanted to find the exact time component count, please use [numpy's Datetime Units](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

```
df['minutes'].astype('timedelta64[m]')/60
```

As explained, the time span in numpy's datetime unit is the range of a 64-bit integer times the length of the date or unit. That is the the time `span for ‘D’ (day) is exactly 24 times longer than the time span for ‘h’ (hour)` which conditions it to convert the minutes into exact time components